# Configure vim-latex suite to use treat .tikz files as ordinary .tex files

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-external, vim, syntax, vim-latex

I use file externalization with tikz, so I usually put the `tikzpicture` environments each in a separate file with extension `.tikz`.
When I open such files with Vim, the syntax is not highlighted, which makes difficult for me to rapidly edit the file.
The basic question is: How can I make Vim use for these files the same syntax coloring used for `.tex` files?
But that question carries another one: How can I make Vim treat these as it does with tex files (so that completions with `<F5>` can be used)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the following lines to the `~/.vimrc` file (or create it if doesn't exist):

```
syntax on
filetype on
au BufNewFile,BufRead *.tikz set filetype=tex
```